# Internet keeps falling on Windows Server 2003

Tags: internet, windows-server-2003, modem

In my office, the internet is provided by an ADSL modem which is connected to a Windows Server 2003 machine. The other computers in the office are connected to this computer through the network.

The problem is that the internet seems to fall every few seconds and then reconnect itself.  This manifests in web pages taking a long time to load, or not loading at all, or only after a few "Refreshes"

1. I have been in contact with the provider of the modem: There is no problem with the ADSL connection. Indeed the ADSL light is steady.
2. I have been in contact with the provider of the Internet service. They report no problem.

The only suggested solution they had was to reset the modem.

This didn't help (other than disconnect the IP Centrix based telephone system - but that is another story)

Does anyone have any ideas? I imagine that there is something wrong with the Windows Server 2003 machine but I have no idea what to check.

Thanks

Comment: as a test try to do continuous ping and see what happens. just pick any target on the web and ping it continuously. If it is indeed provider/model problem you should see time outs. if there is no timeouts it is another problem all together. `ping google.com -t`

Comment: Thanks... I seem to be getting "Request Timed Out" every five minutes or so... Any idea what this could be caused by?

Comment: You need to talk to Provider again and ask to speak to Tier 2 or 3 and tell them the issue that you are experiencing. Once you get connected to someone that knows what they are talking about, tell them that you ran continuous ping and you had been getting time outs ever so often. Tier 1 is not going to be of any help.

Comment: OK. Thanks very much. For the moment the issue seems to have automatically righted itself for the most part. However I will leave this open in case the situation changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is almost certainly that the internet was coming through a computer on which an unused copy of Exchange Server was running, that was hogging a lot of the system resources. I disabled the services of Exchange Server (and prevented them from restarting) and it worked much better afterwards,